# How does the fractional part of $a^n$ behave at infinity？

Tags: calculus, number-theory, analysis

We assume that $a＞2$ is not an integer, it seems that the fractional part of $a^n$ does not vanish at infinity, but I cannot give a proof.

Comment: First thought: set $a = s + k $ where $s$ is the integer part and $k$ is the fractional part ($0<k<1$). What happens when you take this sum to an $n$th power?

Comment: Why $a > 2$ and not $a > 1$?

Comment: @MattiP. I still dont get it.

Comment: Maybe you could do a series expansion and look at how the terms behave.

Comment: @MeesdeVries Maybe we only need $a＞1$ here.

Comment: @MattiP. But the fractional part of $(s+k)^n$ may not be $k^n$, since terms like $C_n^j s^{n-j}k^j$ may add some more.

Comment: Usually, the limit $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} frac({a^n})$$ will not exist, and for large values the fractional part usually is a "random" number.

Comment: Please clarify "at infinity". Maybe, I misinterpreted the question.

Comment: @Peter Just as u thought, infty here means $n \to \infty$. Can u explain a little more that why it is a random number?

Comment: To be honest, know. For really large exponents like in $2.5^{(10^{(10^{10})})}$ there is no hope to determine the fractional part. So, I don't think that we can actually analyze the behaviour for $n\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: @Peter Is there a method to show the nonexistence of the limitation?

Comment: For something like $\sin(n)$ , yes, but I am not sure whether we can prove it in our case as well.

Comment: @Peter OK, thanks a lot.